# Change codification in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a doubt in a thing. Is it possible change codification in oracle with a tool or clausure? I do a insert values in a table with bad codification and my names have characteres with mistakes.

[image]

I want checks this mistakes. Any idea?

Comment: Which tool do you use to insert the data?

Comment: Do just like to find such data or do you like to know how to insert the value properly?

Comment: What is the encoding of your database instance or the column?

Comment: I use slqdeveloper, I want change codification for my data. Do I insert values ​​again to correct errors?

Comment: Correcting wrong data would be difficult because `�` is just a replacement for **any** non valid character. How could you know what `�` means? If you are in good luck then it is only a display issue of your client and the data is not corrupt. In SQL Developer go to Tools menu -> Preferences -> Environment, check Encoding value and change it to UTF-8. Check also if selected font (in Code Editor) is capable to display the characters (but I assume it should be no issue for Spanish letters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your descriptive fields to be able to contain any character, you should declare them as NVARCHAR2, NCHAR or NCLOB, instead of VARCHAR,CHAR and CLOB. Normally the charset used for these types is an UNICODE charset.

Another option is to reinstall the whole instance in order to use, for even for normal strings, the UTF8 charset.

if you go for this second option you must be aware that VARCHAR2(10) means 10 BYTES, not 10 characters: 'ñ' in UTF8 is 2 bytes. If you really mean characters you have to declare them as VARCHAR2(10 CHAR).

Comment: My column is "NOMBRE VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)" but when inserted values the codification was incorrect. I don´t understand why :(

Comment: With a default installation Oracles uses UTF-8 vor `varchar` as well.

Comment: Nowadays the default character set is `AL32UTF8`, so usually there is not need for `NVARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, `NCLOB`. Whether `VARCHAR2(10)` meas 10 BYTES or 10 CHAR depends on `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` setting, you can change it on session level.

Comment: How change it on session level? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = CHAR;`

Comment: @MaríaJoséLunaRego maybe I have been too cryptic: if your database is not installed as UTF-8, you must use "nombre NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR)", not VARCHAR.   the "100 CHAR" part is to explain oracle that you mean 100 characters and not 100 bytes, not to say that you want the db to accept any possible character: only declaring columns as NVARCHAR does it (or having an utf-8 database instance).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `check` constraint.  For instance, if you just want valid letters (from the English alphabet):

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col
    check (regexp_like(col, '^[a-zA-Z]$'))
```

You can easily modify this for whatever character class you care about.

Comment: I really doubt that a Spanish developer  really wants to write an application that dosen't accept all the characters used in his own language... Spanish uses accents, the ñ char, inverted exclamation and question marks, eccetera...

Comment: Yes, I want codification UTF-8. i think that this answers not working for me, but thanks a lot anyway.